# How to use variables in another shell script in my script?

Tags: shell

I have 2 shell scripts. In the first script I have kept the main method. In the 2nd script I have placed all the variables needed for the method since they are too many. Actually the main method needs 8 variables to run, likewise I have some 10 sets of 8 variables.
The main method in script1 has to run for every set of variables. My questions:

How to call these variables from script 2 to the main method in script 1 in order to execute the same? Can I try declaring each set of variables as a function and try to call inside script 1? How to do that?

Please help me with this. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 6):

you can keep the common variables alone in one script, say var.sh 
and add

```
. var.sh #dot Space var.sh
```

in all the scripts where the variables are needed

Comment: @Venky, if this answer works for you, you can reward Vignesh by accepting the answer.

Comment: I already mentioned I have a main method in script1 which has to run for each set of variables in script2. I want to run the main script again and again for each set of variables(var1 to var8 since the main method utilises 8 variables to run). How to make this happen? Please share some ideas.

Comment: I am not very clear with the question. but i will try to answer. just keep the variables and the definition of the main method in the first script but dont call it there. Now load the script as i ve done above and call it in the required scripts

Comment: @Vignesh This works, but why? I tried previously using `./var.sh` and it didn't.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue.
Thanks to Vignesh I made the following changes that worked for me:

Originally the variables were localized w/in the __RequestLogin.sh script:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Loading Data

sh __RequestLogin.sh
sh __ExecuteScript.sh
```

This Updated script allowes access to these variables w/in __ExecuteScript.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Loading Data

. __RequestLogin.sh
. __ExecuteScript.sh
```