# How to use variables in another shell script in a loop in my main script?

Tags: shell, unix

I already mentioned in my [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6070639/how-to-use-variables-in-another-shell-script-in-my-script) that I have a main method in script1 which has to run for each set of variables in script2.

I want to run the main script again and again for each set of variables (var1 to var8 since the main method utilises 8 variables to run) in script2.

How do I achieve this?

Comment: Why aren't you passing them as command-line arguments to script2?

Answer (score 1):

script1:

```
var1=(a b c)
...
var8=(98 545 4)
for (( i = 0 ; i < 3 ; i++ ))
do
  script2 ${var1[i]} ... ${var8[i]}
done
```

script2:

```
if [ $# -eq 9 ]; then  # $# is the total number of arguments.
    var1=$1
    ...
    var8=$8
fi
```

Comment: If another set of variables has to be assigned for the same variable names again, then how it can be done? I mean, after this first set the second set of variables has to be assigned for the main script in script1, like this it has to go on. How to do that?

Comment: Not sure to understand what you mean but I think you want a for loop in script1 that launches script2 with various value `varN`.

Comment: Ok I updated the answer (it should works with Bourne shells. Bash and Zsh at least).